# Organizing common types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, module, naming

I have several Haskell modules (Foo1.hs, Foo2.hs, Foo3.hs) that all depend on the same set of types (Common.hs):

```
...
Foo/Foo1.hs
Foo/Foo2.hs
Foo/Foo3.hs
Foo/Common.hs
...
```

This structure makes the code read well when importing:

```
import Foo.Common
```

What I'm a little worried about is having a lot of same-named Common.hs files throughout the entire project. For example, after adding some bar modules:

```
...
Foo/Foo1.hs
Foo/Foo2.hs
Foo/Foo3.hs
Foo/Common.hs
Bar/Bar1.hs
Bar/Bar2.hs
Bar/Common.hs
...
```

we end up with 2 Common.hs files. Is this fine? Would it be better to rename them somehow (say FooCommon.hs and BarCommon.hs)?

Doing so would seem to make the importing a little bit more awkward:

```
import Foo.FooCommon
```

Though this might be just a matter of taste.

Comment: I think having modules named `Common` in functional programming is about as useful as having classes named `Util` in OOP.

Comment: I've found this talk very useful for ideas how to organize haskell project https://jaspervdj.be/posts/2017-12-07-getting-things-done-in-haskell.html

Comment: Using FooCommon and BarCommon looks far worse to me.

Comment: @MarkSeemann How would you propose to organize a set of common types used by several modules? In OOP, this usually not an issue since each type has its own file/module. One module per type looks overkill in Haskell, though. Defining types in a "scattered" way across many modules can require mutually recursive modules (which are not very convenient in GHC). A `Types`/`Internal`/`Common` module works, but does not look very elegant. Ideally, module dependency should form a tree, avoiding the issue, but often it is a DAG instead.

Comment: @chi I can't answer such a question without knowing what those common types are. Often, the use of vague words like `Manager`, `Controller`, `Util`, `Common`, `Core`, etc. could indicate that there's an implicit abstraction that could benefit from being made explicit. I think that applies to OOP as well as FP. Exactly what that abstraction is, though, is context-dependent, so it's not something I can answer in general.

Comment: For _exporting_, note that it is possible to define both a `Foo.hs` file and a `Foo/` directory, containing many modules. It is possible to write a `module Foo` that imports and re-exports the deeper modules, so to provide a simple interface to the library user. This does not help to organize common types internally to the library, though.

Comment: @chi Often, though, if one has a set of `data` or `newtype` definitions that are required by more than one module, those *could* be the types that model the problem space being solved by the software. In a business context, those are often collectively termed a *Domain Model*, so that could be a slightly more explicit name than `Common`.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I agree. I think in the past I was able to find solutions to each specific case, none of which was a general solution. Probably a completely general solution does not even exist.

Comment: @MarkSeemann In this particular case each module in "Foo" represents a set of domain-specific computations. All of them return the same type (let's call it ComputationResult), so I neither can nor want to define it in every Foo. Also, I don't want to define it in Foo1 and then import it to Foo2. Foo1 and Foo2 are completely separate and can perfectly exist without each other.

Comment: @PetrasPurlys Doesn't that fit the scenario from my previous comment? If it's domain-specific, then would it make sense to use the name of that domain as the name of the module, instead of `Common`?